# Oreilly Head First Android Development

Tags: android

Now I'm learning Android via this book, but I'm stuck. I'm on page 95 if anyone cares and I need to make a button that does something when I click on it.

[image: pic 1]

As you can see my "brands" parameter is red, when I hover over it it says: "Cannot resolve symbol brands". What does it mean?

Is my XML wrong?

[image: XML pic]

Or my Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a `TextView` with id `textView` instead of `brands`:

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```

Change it to:

```
android:id="@+id/brands"
```

Comment: Welp, that was dumb.. As you can see im very new to this :D Thanks for the help!